# Python Selenium, how to wait for an element to be clickable iteratively

Tags: python, html, selenium, webdriverwait

I need to download images from site pages using Python Selenium. I select webelements of those images and click them iteratively:

```
...
THUMBNAILS = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'lg-thumb-item')]/img")

for thumbnail in THUMBNAILS:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(thumbnail))
    thumbnail.click()
```

the problem with this code is:

```
find_element() argument after * must be an iterable, not WebElement
```

I tracebacked this error and it occurs only when the previous code is triggered.
The problem lies in the `element_to_be_clickable(thumbnail)`, it wants a tuple specifying the selector and its value, not a `WebElement`.
I can't figure out a way to extract a selector value from `thumbnail` (like xpath or css) to feed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

I could feed the function the xpath like this:

```
THUMBNAILS = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'lg-thumb-item')]/img")

for thumbnail in THUMBNAILS:
    src = thumbnail.get_attribute('src')
    WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//img[@src='{src}']")))
    thumbnail.click()
```